# How to get the closed-from of the series with Legendre polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, closed-form, legendre-polynomials

I want to find the closed-form of the Legendre series of

$S(i,j)=\sum_{n=j}^\infty {\varepsilon}^n n^i P_n^j(\cos \theta)$

with $i$ a arbitray integer, $j$ a postive integer, $\varepsilon$ a real number between $0$ and $1$.

I find $S(0,j)=\frac{(2j)!}{j! 2^j} \frac{(\sin \theta)^j \varepsilon^j}{s^{2j+1}}$ with $s=(1-2\varepsilon \cos \theta+{\varepsilon}^2)^{1/2}$ in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01535777) (Eq. 5).

And it is easy to know that $S(i+1,j)=\varepsilon \frac{d S(i,j)}{d \varepsilon}$.

How to use the recurrence relation to get the closed-form of $S(i,j)$? Do we need to solve them differential-difference equation? Thank you.